# Kafka RabbitMQ connector - can only get byte arrays

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I've set up a connector to pull from a RabbitMQ queue and push into a Kafka topic. The connector runs and the queue empties out. But when I look at the topic with either kafka-console-consumer or kafkacat, every entry looks like a byte arrray - `[B@xxxxxxxx`.

The RabbitMQ message payloads are all JSON. What do I need to do to get JSON back out from Kafka? I've tried `value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter` as well as using ByteArrayDeserializer with the console consumer.

connect-standalone.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/home/robbie/kafka/plugins
```

RabbitMQSourceConnector.properties:

```
name=rabbitmq
tasks.max=1
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector
rabbitmq.prefetch.count=500
rabbitmq.automatic.recovery.enabled=false
rabbitmq.network.recovery.interval.ms=10000
rabbitmq.topology.recovery.enabled=true
rabbitmq.queue=test1
rabbitmq.username=testuser1
rabbitmq.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
rabbitmq.host=rmqhost
rabbitmq.port=5672
kafka.topic=rabbitmq.test1
```

Comment: Have you tried using the JSONConverter.?

Comment: Yes. The JSONConverter doesn't even work. I couldn't find a solution for that, either. It causes: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Conversion error: null value for field that is required and has no default value

Comment: Can you show the full connector configuration properties?

Comment: Connector config files added.

Comment: This person seems to not get byte arrays https://stackoverflow.com/q/59632068/2308683 Maybe you should try using AvroConverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set

```
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
```

I wrote [a blog](https://rmoff.net/2020/01/08/streaming-messages-from-rabbitmq-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect/) up on this just today :)

Comment: Well I would *swear* that I tried that, but had no success. But I tried it again and now everything is awesome. I don't quite understand why that's the correct choice yet, but then I started with Kafka this week and have a long way to go. Thanks!