# Kafka connect is sending a malformed json

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to perform a proof of concept using kafka-connect with a rabbitMQ connector. Basically, I have two simple spring boot applications; a RabbitMQ producer and a Kafka consumer. The consumer can not handle the messages from the connector because it's transforming somehow my JSON message; RabbitMQ sends `{"transaction": "PAYMENT", "amount": "$125.0"}` and kafka-connect prints `X{"transaction": "PAYMENT", "amount": "$125.0"}`. Please note the `X` at the beginning. If I add a field, let's say `"foo": "bar"` then that letter becomes a `t` or whatever.

*Dockerfile (connector)*:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:5.3.2
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-rabbitmq:latest
```

Please generate the image as follows: `docker build . -t rabbit-connector`, so you can reference it in the docker-compose file as `rabbit-connector`.

*docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  kafka-connect-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.3.2
    networks: 
      - kafka-connect-network
    ports:
      - '31000:31000'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: "localhost"
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 31000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.3.2
    networks: 
      - kafka-connect-network
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '31001:31001'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: "localhost"
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 31001

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.3.2
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    networks: 
      - kafka-connect-network
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
      - '31002:31002'
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:2181
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_JMX_HOSTNAME: "localhost"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_JMX_PORT: 31002

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
    networks: 
      - kafka-connect-network
    ports:
      - '15672:15672'
      - '5672:5672'

  kafka-connect:
    image: rabbit-connector
    networks: 
      - kafka-connect-network
    ports:
      - '8083:8083'
      - '31004:31004'
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:29092"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "ERROR"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: "localhost"
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 31004
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
      - rabbitmq

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.3.2
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    networks: 
      - kafka-connect-network
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
      - '31005:31005'
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      KAFKAREST_JMX_HOSTNAME: "localhost"
      KAFKAREST_JMX_PORT: 31005
```

*schema.avsc*:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "CustomMessage",
  "namespace": "com.poc.model",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "transaction",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

So here I am using a `StringConverter` for my key (which I don't care to be honest) and `AvroConverter` for the value. Maybe I am missing something or I'm misconfiguring my kafka-connect worker.

My connector configuration is (*connector-config.json*):

```
 {
   "name" : "rabbit_to_kafka_poc",
   "config" : {
    "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max" : "1",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "kafka.topic" : "spectrum-message",
    "rabbitmq.queue" : "spectrum-queue",
    "rabbitmq.username": "guest",
    "rabbitmq.password": "guest",
    "rabbitmq.host": "rabbitmq",
    "rabbitmq.port": "5672",
    "rabbitmq.virtual.host": "/"
   } 
 }
```

To register my connector I do `curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @connector-config.json`.

Once I configure everything, I run the following command to print out my messages:

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
                            --topic spectrum-message \
                            --from-beginning
```

And the JSON starts with a letter, so my question is **why is this happening**? I think something is encoding my message but my rabbitMQ producer is sending a plain JSON message. I can confirm by testing with a RabbitMQ consumer and debugging my application to the point where the message is being sent out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [ByteArrayConverter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-128%3A+Add+ByteArrayConverter+for+Kafka+Connect). It's just bytes that the connector pulls from RabbitMQ - it won't try to coerce it to a schema. Even if you serialise it to Avro, the schema is just a single field of bytes:

```
$ curl -s -XGET localhost:8081/subjects/rabbit-test-avro-00-value/versions/1 | jq '.'
{
  "subject": "rabbit-test-avro-00-value",
  "version": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "schema": "\"bytes\""
}
```

If you want to write it to a topic in Avro (which is a good idea) *with a schema* then use something like Kafka Streams or ksqlDB to do this, applying a stream processor to the source topic which Kafka Connect writes to with the ByteArrayConverter.

For example in ksqlDB you would do:

```
-- Inspect the topic - ksqlDB recognises the format as JSON

ksql> PRINT 'rabbit-test-00' FROM BEGINNING;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1578477403591,"ROWKEY":"null","transaction":"PAYMENT","amount":"$125.0"}
{"ROWTIME":1578477598555,"ROWKEY":"null","transaction":"PAYMENT","amount":"$125.0"}

-- Declare the schema
CREATE STREAM rabbit (transaction VARCHAR,
                      amount VARCHAR)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='rabbit-test-00',
        VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

-- Reserialise to Avro
CREATE STREAM TRANSACTIONS WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', 
                                 KAFKA_TOPIC='reserialised_data') AS
  SELECT *
    FROM rabbit
    EMIT CHANGES;
```

For more details, see [this blog](https://rmoff.net/2020/01/08/streaming-messages-from-rabbitmq-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect/) that I've written up.

Comment: I figured it out myself yesterday, but I was not aware of ksqldb schemas. Thanks. Is it possible to generate that schema from POJOs in Java or manual work is required?

Comment: You have to declare it manually in ksqlDB if you're wanting to map the data to a schema from schema-less (e.g. JSON)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have JSON messages, you have Avro messages coming out of Kafka based on the usages of the AvroConverter.

That letter is not actually a letter, but your terminal showing the UTF8 representation of the first 5 bytes of the binary data. That commonly happens when using regular console consumer, rather than the `avro-console-consumer` which itself will parse the bytes out of the topic correctly for Avro data

If you want JSON throughout, use the JSONConverter instead

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. I am, using `kafka-avro-console-consumer`. Edited

Comment: Have you passed in `--property schema.registry.url` as a well?

Comment: Yeah, it throws an error because of the `X` at the beginning: 
```
Processed a total of 1 messages
[2020-01-07 20:51:34,685] ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$:76)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 21
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /schemas/ids/21
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:610)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:507)
```
So I did: `curl http://localhost:8081/schemas/ids/21` -> `{"schema":"\"bytes\""}%` ??

Comment: Obviously my schema is wrong. I'll try posting the schema as it should be again

Comment: I created my schema `curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d"{\"schema\":$SCHEMA}" http://lo
calhost:8081/subjects/spectrum-message/versions` and ran `curl http://localhost:8081/schemas/ids/1`, I get: `{"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"SpectrumMessage\",\"namespace\":\"com.up
grade.model\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"transaction\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"}`

but the error still remains: `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /schemas/ids/2` and `curl http://localhost:8081/schemas/ids/2` -> `{"schema":"\"bytes\""}%`

Comment: Why is that schema registered if I did not do it?

Comment: I don't recognize that

Comment: `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /schemas/ids/21` is saying you're not putting http before the address of the URL, in fact you've not given anything as the address but the end path... And if you use a source connector, you shouldn't be posting your own schemas since the connector generates its own and doesn't magically use what you've provided